# Using MySQL, why doesn't Hibernate/JPA create foreign key constraints for me?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Documenting this here because I just wasted an hour trying to figure this out.

I have an entity Foo with:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "barId")
private Bar bar;
```

Why does Hibernate not create a foreign key constraint on foo.bar -> bar.id ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because MySQL does not support foreign key constraints on tables created with ENGINE=MyISAM.  You need to create (both!) tables with ENGINE=InnoDB.  You can do so by tweaking `my.cnf`, and adding a default, or by using a special variable in your JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?characterEncoding=utf8&sessionVariables=storage_engine=InnoDB
```

Comment: FWIW, in MySQL 5.5, InnoDB is *finally* the default storage engine out of the box.

Comment: I've added this to my JDBC connection string and now I get `java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'storage_engine'`

Comment: I've added this to my JDBC connection string and now I get java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'storage_engine'

Answer (score 18):

As suggested here [Hibernate: Create Mysql InnoDB tables instead of MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459265/hibernate-create-mysql-innodb-tables-instead-of-myisam) you can also change **Hibernate dialect** to use

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

which is less invasive.

Just wanted to add this as an alternative solution.

Comment: I'm using JPA to create my schema, where is the above placed? in the persistance.xml?

Comment: it goes in the hibernate.properties file

Answer (score 10):

With SpringBoot you can set `application.properties` to:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: this solved my problem while working with Spring Boot.

Comment: If this doesn't work, try this: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect

Comment: This actually worked for me spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect