# Using "TYPE = InnoDB" in MySQL throws exception

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.0, mysql-5.6

When I try to execute the following `SQL` in `MySQL`, I'm getting error:

SQL:

```
        SQL = "CREATE TABLE Ranges (";
        SQL += "ID varchar(20) NOT NULL, ";
        SQL += "Descriptions longtext NULL, ";
        SQL += "Version_Number int NULL, ";
        SQL += "Row_Updated bigint NULL, ";
        SQL += "Last_Updated datetime NULL, ";
        SQL += "XML longtext NULL, ";
        SQL += "PRIMARY KEY (ID)";
        SQL += ") " + "TYPE = InnoDB";
```

Error:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "TYPE = InnoDB"**

But if I remove `"TYPE = InnoDB"`, then the query works fine.

Previously the query worked fine, ie in `MySQL 5.0`. But when I upgraded to `MySQL 5.6`, I'm getting the above error.

Any Suggestions / Alternatives ... ??

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `ENGINE = Innodb` instead of `TYPE = InnoDB`. `TYPE` was removed in 5.1.

Comment: Worked. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

`TYPE = InnoDB` was deprecated in `MySQL 5.0` and was removed in `My SQL 5.1` and later versions.

You now have to use `ENGINE = InnoDB`