# Spring Boot Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

So i wanted to make a simple CRUD apps and  i used the MYSQL Workbench for the database .
My connection in MySQL Workbench

```
Hostname : 127.0.0.1
Port : 3306
```

I don't use password in MySQL Workbench.

and now my application properties looks like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_management_system?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

The error that i'm getting

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table employees (id bigint not null auto_increment, email_id varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), primary key (id)) type=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
```

and another one at the bottom part

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1
```

Please can someone help ?

Comment: Maybe this response is good for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066024/what-is-the-mariadb-dialect-class-name-for-hibernate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your database does not support the InnoDB engine.
Try to replace

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
```

by

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I needed to **inspect the sql** that it was generating by adding these two lines to my application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

And only then I was able to copy the sql, paste it into the console editor and get a more detailed description for the error. There it complained I was trying to **name my table with a reserved word**. I changed that and it worked (I was using postgres).

Answer (score 1):

Use this query instead:

```
create table employees 
  ( 
     id         bigint not null auto_increment, 
     email_id   varchar(255), 
     first_name varchar(255), 
     last_name  varchar(255), 
     primary key (id) 
  ) 
engine=InnoDB;
```

For reference: [Using "TYPE = InnoDB" in MySQL throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338876/using-type-innodb-in-mysql-throws-exception)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you now try to access either database not exist or the default "information_schema" which this user is not allowed to create a table on it so simply

Create a new database:

```
create database example;
```

Create a new user to work on this database or you can use root access but the new user will be better try to not use root user everywhere

```
create user 'exampleuser'@'%' identified by 'PASSWORD;
```

Then assign the user to have all permissions on this db

```
grant all on example.* to 'exampleuser'@'%';
```

Finally, make sure you update your spring configuration

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/example
spring.datasource.username=exampleuser
spring.datasource.password=12345
```