# How can I configure Hibernate 5 to force Mysql create tables using Innodb engine?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, innodb, dialect

Spent several hours to solve this issue, gave up finally.
I need my app to create Innodb tables, but by default they are created in Myisam engine.
I've tried to set property,

`<property name="hibernate.dialect.storage_engine">innodb</property>` but it won't work.

`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect` - deprecated

Found out there is `org.hibernate.dialect.InnoDBStorageEngine` class
but I couldn't set it to `property name="hibernate.dialect"` in my hibernate.cfg.xml because of

> org.hibernate.dialect.InnoDBStorageEngine' is not assignable to 'org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect

reason. Do you have any idea where I can set InnoDBStorageEngine?
Or is there another way to force Hibernate use innodb while creating tables?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate: Create Mysql InnoDB tables instead of MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459265/hibernate-create-mysql-innodb-tables-instead-of-myisam)

Comment: What is `default_storage_engine` in my.cnf?  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Rick James, issue is solved, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Hibernate 5.2 documentaton](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html) suggests what to do in deprecation description

> MySQL57InnoDBDialect - Deprecated
>
> Use "hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb" environment variable or JVM system property instead.

So use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect` in combination with this property set.