# Hibernate dialect for MySQL 8?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Is there a Hibernate dialect for MySQL 8? Or should I use the org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect that ships with Hibernate?
I'm using hibernate 5.2.16

Answer (score 118):

MySQL8Dialect(org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect) is available in hibernate bundle 5.3.1.Final. You can use:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Comment: Awesome... spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect  worked perfectly for me -  HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect. Wondering why this is not accepted yet? May be I am using Hibernate 5.3.7 with Springboot 2.1.2.

Comment: Is there a way I can use this dialect in hibernate 4.1.10 ?  I am on java 1.7 right now and looks like I need to upgrade to java 1.8 in order to use hibernate 5.3.1 which is  big issue for me .  Any help ?

Comment: "MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead"

Answer (score 28):

yes, For MySQL8, use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`

Comment: In Hibernate 6 the `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` seems to be deprecated :C

Comment: My tools show that ...MySQL8Dialect is deprecated;

Answer (score 23):

If you are using Gradle (e.g. for Grails) just configure:

in application.yml

```
dataSource:
...
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
....
```

in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17'
    ...
```

Pay attention on mysql-connector version and non-deprecated driver class name

Answer (score 11):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
```

got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54672737)

Answer (score 6):

Since Hibernate 6, `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` is deprecated. And now it is recommended to use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`. See [Hibernate JavaDoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL8Dialect.html) for reference

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a couple of weeks old, but for completeness it appears Hibernate 5.3 does have a MySQL8 dialect

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html

I have not used it, so I cannot comment on its quality, but the support appears to be there.

Comment: I try it, there is  error `Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]` ,mysql version is 8. hibernate version is 5.0.1. I revert it to `MySQL57Dialect` is work fine

Comment: Can’t speak to much, but unless there’s a typo in your version number of Hibernate, that would be my first guess. It requires at least 5.3

Answer (score 4):

Yes, MySQL8Dialect for MySql 8.
In my case I have used MySQL8Dialect for MySql 8 in my spring boot application by following way:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SpringBoot

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Answer (score 2):

From **hibernate version 6** on you should use **MySQLDialect** so

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

instead of

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

MySQL8Dialect is now deprecated, see:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL8Dialect.html

Comment: no need to declare explicitly, you can use  :  org.hibernate.dialect

Answer (score 1):

Looking over at [MySQL 8's release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/), MySQL 8.x has been in development and has only been out for GA since 2018-04-19 (less than a month ago), so I doubt there would be a dialect already made specifically for it.

You can see a list of all hibernate dialects [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html), and as you can see, there is no MySQL 8 dialect.

`MySQLDialect` should only be used for MySQL 5 and earlier whereas `MySQL57Dialect` should be used for MySQL 5.x as well as 8.x for now.

Comment: there is ' MySQL8Dialect ' ,you can check it .https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL8Dialect.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by simply adding the configuration below to my `application.properties` file.

```
#Hibernate

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

spring.jpa.driverClassName= com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar query as I installed MySQL 8 Server and tried to interact with the same using my Spring Boot Application.

But I was unable to do so.

When I explored the Source Code of MySQL5Dialect class, it's documentation clearly mentions that this dialect class has been dedicated to MySQL 5.X versions.

I am not sure whether it supports MySQL 8.X versions.

Thus I would suggest to use MySQL 5.X till an official dialect is released with Hibernate.