# Can't use String as @Id with SpringData

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data

I want to create new table on my database using this class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "currency_rate")
public class CurrencyRate {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "source_currency")
    private String sourceCurrency;

    @Column(name = "target_currency")
    private String targetCurrency;

    @Column(name = "exchange_rate")
    private double exchangeRate;

    @Column
    private Date date;

    @PrePersist
    public void generateID() {            
        this.id = this.date.toString().replace("-", "") + sourceCurrency + targetCurrency;
    }
    //getters, setters
}
```

When I try to run my application with property

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I got this exception

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Looks like I can't use Spring as my ID? Changing type to Long solves problem, but I really wanted to go with String with this one. From what I searched, it should be totally doable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use @Id with String Type in JPA / Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622716/how-to-use-id-with-string-type-in-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: @YassinHajaj: No, it is not a duplicate. Please dont't generate SPAM. If you cannot exactly tell if this is a duplicate, then press SKIP when you are reviewing questions. LOW QUALITY comments are as bad as low quality questions.

Comment: @mentallurg This is why the sentence starts with *Possible duplicate of*

Comment: i found a solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459265/hibernate-create-mysql-innodb-tables-instead-of-myisam

Answer (score 0):

As per tutorial from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm, the attribute can be defined by `Column` annotation in details.

> @Column Annotation The @Column annotation is used to specify the
>   details of the column to which a field or property will be mapped. You
>   can use column annotation with the following most commonly used
>   attributes −
>
> name attribute permits the name of the column to be explicitly
>   specified.
>
> length attribute permits the size of the column used to map a value
>   particularly for a String value.
>
> nullable attribute permits the column to be marked NOT NULL when the
>   schema is generated.
>
> unique attribute permits the column to be marked as containing only
>   unique values.

What matters here for your question is `length` parameter, maybe you can try annotate your id like below:

```
  @Id
  @Column(length = 100)
  private String id;
```