# Why database table is not automatically generated for a Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with Spring Data JPA, the implementation of JPA is hibernate.
The database I'm using is Mysql.
The Entity will be mapped to a Mysql table and the table is created automatically when I launched the Spring application. However, when I changed the ID from Integer to String, the table is disappeared and can't be created anymore. I'm a little confused why it happens. Let me post the code comparison as below.

The `Entity` before:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity 
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  private String email;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

}
```

The `Entity` after:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity 
public class User {
  @Id
  private String id;

  private String name;

  private String email;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

}
```

The `CrudRepository` before:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import gearon.model.entity.User;

// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

@Component
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

The `CrudRepository` after:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import gearon.model.entity.User;

// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

@Component
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

}
```

### Edit1

The error output in console is:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
```

and it's caused by

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

### Edit2

Found a similar question without answer but votes, it seems that more people met this issues.

[Can't use String as @Id with SpringData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660942/cant-use-string-as-id-with-springdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is [related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814594/10648865). Basically, depending on the version of MySQL you are using and the encoding of your strings, the maximum VARCHAR size can vary.

I don't know those parameters of you, but to be safe I would define my String PK with a maximum length of 191. Depending on your version of MySQL and encoding, can be higher.

```
@Id
@Column(length = 191)
private String id;
```

Comment: I just went through hibernate annotation and decided to try the length parameter, at the same time, I found that you have posted this answer. Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In case If you don't specify an id generation strategy, Hibernate will by default use `GenerationType.AUTO`.

If you want a `String` UUID as an id, you could use

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "PR_KEY")
private String prKey;
```

Refer [how-to-use-id-with-string-type-in-jpa-hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622716/how-to-use-id-with-string-type-in-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have merged your update, the error is still here and I have check the console, please check the update of my question.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes-in-mysql-5-6