# Hibernate query ends up in SQL syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have created a `UserPreferences` bean. The primary key being `id` column. Here is the definition of the bean:

```
@Entity
public class UserPreferences {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(unique = true)
    @ColumnDefault("")
    private String id;

    private String email;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Now I use `Kotlin` to insert data in this bean. Here is the code to do so:

```
val newUserPreferences = UserPreferences().apply { email = newUserRequest.email }
mUserPreferenceService.save(newUserPreferences)
```

Lets assume that `newUserRequest.email` is not `null`. The `auto-dll` setting in my `application.yml` is `update`. When this code is executed, I see that `Hibernate` generates following query for creating the table:

```
create table user_preferences (
   id varchar(255) default  not null
   email varchar(255),
   primary key (id)
) engine=MyISAM
```

At this point, the application fails to load with the following error:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'not null,

Looking at the exception, it is very clear that the code is failing because instead of using an empty `String` as default value, hibernate is simply putting a blank space in the generated query. So here are my questions:

1. Should this be treated as a bug in Hibernate?
2. How to handle this situation where I would like to have an empty String `""` as column default value?

Comment: Should there be a comma after `id varchar(255) default  not null`?

Comment: Yes there is, somehow I missed to copy it in my question

Comment: oh okk.
because the error mentioned 'right syntax near not null', hence caught your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Hibernate user, but I found https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/documentation/src/test/java/org/hibernate/userguide/schema/ColumnDefaultTest.java shows:

```
@ColumnDefault("'N/A'")
```

It appears that when you define a default value for a SQL string type, you must use SQL string delimiters (single quotes) inside the Java string. In your case, since you want an empty string, you'd use:

```
@ColumnDefault("''")
```

The other way to define a default is to set an attribute in the `@Column` annotation, as shown in another Stack Overflow answer: [How to set default value in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110266/how-to-set-default-value-in-hibernate)

So this may not be a bug, but it's a usage of Hibernate that is counter-intuitive for some users, and perhaps not documented clearly.

P.S.: I would count it as a bug that Hibernate still generates CREATE TABLE statements with `engine=MyISAM` [unless you specify the right hibernate.dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459265/hibernate-create-mysql-innodb-tables-instead-of-myisam). That storage engine is not recommended. MyISAM is slower than InnoDB in most cases, and fails to support any ACID properties. MySQL has been phasing out MyISAM, and I don't recommend using it for any current projects.

Comment: Thanks Bill for you explanation.