# Spring Boot + JPA : @Transactional annotation : Roll back is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am using @Transactional with spring boot and jpa. But it is not working. Can somebody help out.

My inserts are in myDAO which is autowired in service class. Below code is method of service class which is implementing service interface

```
class MyService implements Service {

@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
    public ResponseVO createOrder(params) {
    myDAO.insertInTable1(param);
    myDAO.insertInTable2(param);//I kept wrong table name in this query such that it throws exception
         }

 }
```

Comment: nothing is wrong here, give as more info :)

Comment: Your rollback is only for `RuntimeException`, and wrong table don't create an `RuntimeException`. Read the `@Transactional` manual.

Comment: @Zorglube, I tried with creating new Runtime Exception with new. Even though no rollback.

Comment: It seems you don't understand what you're doing, you don't need to forge an exception yourself, you need to choose for what kind of exception you rollback or not.

Comment: From where gets the createOrder method called?

Comment: createOrder is called from controller class

Comment: Show the `MyDao` implementation, also which database are you using? If you are using MySQL make sure you are using a table store that supports transactions.

Comment: I am using MYSql, with engine MyISAM.
in DAO I am just inserting data into table1 and table 2 using JPA save and saveall methods.(JPARepository)

Comment: If you want to rollback a transaction on an Exception then the method `must` throw an Exception... You're not throwing one here... add `public ResponseVO createOrder(params) throws Exception {...}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue is with MySQL Database engine. My engine was MYIsam which doesn't supports Transactions. I changed my DB engine to InnoDB and its working. Thanks for the contributions. Below are the queries for the same.

SELECT ENGINE 
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE
  TABLE_NAME = 'tabel_name'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA='db_name';

ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = INNODB;

Comment: For changing to INNODB using the hibernate dialect refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459265/hibernate-create-mysql-innodb-tables-instead-of-myisam

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers!!

Comment: I wouldalso try Exception.class in the rollbackFor part, to discard it is not about the type of Exception being thrown?

Comment: Problem was simple bro.. he didn't have a `throws` clause ;) 

```public ResponseVO createOrder(params) {} 
```

Answer (score 2):

`RuntimeException` are already handled

replace with `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` to manage all checked exception and will work

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell from the amount of code given. I do know that you shouldn't need the `rollbackFor` if it is `RuntimeException`. Those are always rolled back. I am guessing your table name error is a `SQLException` which implements `Exception`. You would have to have `rollbackFor` be `rollbackFor=SQLException.class`, and I would only keep that in while verifying that rollbacks happen. Only add the rollbackFor if you are throwing checked exceptions in methods called by the service.

Comment: I tried that also. But no use. But generally Runtime exception will handle all types of exceptions. So it shoudl catch this exception also and rollback.

Comment: SQLException is a subclass of Exception, not RuntimeException. RuntimeException is a subclass of Exception. Only subclasses of RuntimeException would get rolled back.

Answer (score -1):

In Spring Boot, OpenSessionInView is enabled by default, so your rollback does not work because each time you call `myDAO.insertInTableX()`, a Commit is performed.

So to remove this behaviour and have your `@Transactional` works correctly, add this :

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

To your **application.properties**

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot) for more