# Spring boot hibernate change engine from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to create a ER Diagram from mysqldump file by reverse engineer,
everything works but relationship connections wont show in Workbench.

Note on Workbench:
Foreign keys can only be defined for certain storage engines (like InnoDB).

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME,
    ->        ENGINE
    -> FROM   information_schema.TABLES
    -> WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_example';

+--------------------+--------+
| TABLE_NAME         | ENGINE |
+--------------------+--------+
| difficulty         | MyISAM |
| durations          | MyISAM |
+--------------------+--------+
```

what i've tried:

**application.properties**

```
hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

So i'm trying to change the engine to InnoDB but keeps recreating the database as MyISAM

Comment: you can try this : spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459265/hibernate-create-mysql-innodb-tables-instead-of-myisam

Comment: Worked! relations working on workbench as well!